# Java paypal merchant SDK transaction search works on OSX but not on Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, paypal

I'm building a Java application that utilizes the Java Paypal Merchant SDK and have come across an issue that I cannot figure out.

The app works perfectly when I run it on the machine that I developed it on (a mac in this case) but when I move it to the dedicated machine (a VPS running widows server 2012 in) it behaves completely different on this one call to the Paypal api. Everything else works perfectly.

The method call in question:

```
service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService("PaypalInfo/sdk_config.properties");
TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponse = null;

try {
transactionSearchResponse = service.transactionSearch(transactionSearchReq);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On OSX this call returns the correct information, on Windows it returns nothing, the SOAP call and return is different. In both instances the program was packaged the same, so I know that is not the issue. I have followed all the guides on the sdk github but can not get it to work.

I can post the logger output which has the XML of the SOAP calls if that would help answer the question.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

SOAP request:
http://pastebin.com/xrpRVywx

SOAP response:
http://pastebin.com/aRT3JvbS

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about the PayPal API and the response you are getting, it is hard to say, but off the top of my head I would guess that either:

1. That config file is not where you think it is on your VPS, and the API call isn't being made with the credentials or other configuration that is in that file; or
2. The firewall on the VPS is blocking your outgoing connection.

Comment: I can edit my OP with the call and response. I've already checked and double checked the path, the credentials are correct. I think that what you said about the VPS blocking the connection might be what's happening. Which program do I need to unblock in order to allow the connection through?

Comment: If your firewall was blocking you, there would be no response at all. That you are getting a proper response from the API was not clear to me from the original post. Skimming the PayPal API docs, it looks like the response is properly formatted, there is just no data specific to your TransactionSearch call. Perhaps your request parameters are different between environments? If you're sure they are the same, then I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: They are the exact same :(. I suppose I could maybe open a support ticket on the paypal developer site.